# Vba Numberformat muliple condtions to format cell value

Tags: vba, conditional-statements, number-formatting

Dear all i want to format my cell based on the Cell value. There are 3 possible Conditions:

1. Cell is larger than 0.05 -> the Value should stay the same but be fromated to 0.0
2. Cell is smaller than 0.05  -> the Value should be replaced with a String "a.C."
3. Cell is Zero -> the Value should be replaced with a Dash"

I found this[Solution](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/dash-if-zero-vba.1039762/) for the dashes and could combine it with the number formating

```
.NumberFormat = "0.0;[=0]---"
```

This works. but if i add an additonal argument the vba code breaks.

```
.NumberFormat = "0.0;[=0]---;[<0.05]a.C."
```

Does not work. Would you mind telling me what i am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

FOr what ever reason this Order seems to work:

.NumberFormat = "[=0]---;[<0.05] ""a.C."";0.0 "